# count number of records in column using single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a `student` table with 3 fields: `name`, `number` and `result`. `result` field contains either `Pass` or `Fail`. My question is how to count the number of `pass` and number of `fail` using single query?

Comment: try count() and group by status

Comment: Assuming you want the result for each course then your query will be `SELECT  course, sum(if(result='Pass', 1, 0)) AS 'PASS', sum(if(result='Fail', 1, 0)) AS 'FAIL' FROM tbl GROUP BY course`.  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.result, count(1)
from mytable t
group by t.result
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT result, count(result) FROM student GROUP BY result;
```